# Promise in cron job

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I try to run the code without success.
Only the first call works in start of node.

Here is my current code:

```
const Product = require('../models/Product');
const Price = require('../models/Price');

const cron = require('node-cron');
const amazon = require('amazon-product-api');
const util = require('util');
const _ = require('underscore')
/**
 * Cron job
 * Tracking price
 */

exports.track = () => {

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {

    const client = amazon.createClient({
        awsId: process.env.AWS_ID,
        awsSecret: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
        assocId: process.env.AWS_TAG
    });

  Promise.all([Product.getAsin()])
    .then(([asin]) => {
      let listId = _.pluck(asin, '_id');
      let listAsin = _.pluck(asin, 'asin');
      if (asin.length === 0) {
        return
      }

      client.itemLookup({
          idType: 'ASIN',
          itemId: listAsin,
          domain: 'webservices.amazon.fr',
          responseGroup: 'ItemAttributes,OfferFull,SalesRank'
      }).then((results) => {
        for(i=0; i<listId.length; i++){
            results[i].id = listId[i];
        }
        for(res of results) {
          Price.addPrice({
            asin: res.ASIN[0],
            product: res.id,
            salePrice: res.Offers[0].Offer[0].OfferListing[0].Price[0].Amount[0],
          })
        }
        console.log(listId);
        Product.makeUpdate(listId);

      }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          console.log(util.inspect(err, true, null));
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
})
}
```

Requests to MongoDB are asynchronous.

**Product**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
const _ = require('underscore');
const moment = require('moment');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  domain: String,
  originUrl: { type: String, unique: true },
  check: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  ean: String,
  asin: String
}, { timestamps: true });

Object.assign(productSchema.statics, {
  getAsin() {
    return this.find(
      { updatedAt: { $lt: oneMin },
        asin: { $ne: null }
      }
    ).limit(10)
    .select({ asin: 1 })
    .exec()//.then((tuples) => _.pluck(tuples, 'asin'))
  },
  makeUpdate(id) {
    console.log('list des ID updated => ' + id);
    return this.update({ _id: { $in: id } }, { $inc : { "check": 1 } } , {multi: true}).exec();
  }
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product;

const oneMin = moment().subtract(1, 'minutes').format();
```

Also, since I'm absolutely new to JavaScript and Node.js in general, any best practices or general tips will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you paste console output?

Comment: Also, as a hint: chante `client.itemLookup...` by `return client.itemLookup...` and remove its catch (move inspect things to last catch if you want). I understand it returns a promise, so better let promise chain to flow to last fullfilment.

Comment: `Promise.all([Product.getAsin()])` - looks rather redundant - does `Product.getAsin()` return a promise?

Comment: "only the first call works" - what happens after that? errors? terminates? house catches on fire?

Comment: Thanks @bitifet : I have no error on console. I have try return client.itemLookup... same issue

Comment: That was a hint, for better coding. Your code wasn't wrong regarding that. Only less clever. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX : Any error, the "cron job" continue but any return... Product.getAsin() return a promise. Like this :   getAsin() {
    return this.find(
      { updatedAt: { $lt: oneMin },
        asin: { $ne: null }
      }
    ).limit(10)
    .select({ asin: 1 })
    .exec()

Comment: Ah ok thank you :) I have update my post for add the code of Product

Comment: @jaribu - so the cron job triggers once - then never again, and there's no errors? If you put `console.log("running");` at just above `const client = amazon.createClient({` ... does "running" get output every minute?

Comment: Why are you doing `Promise.all([Product.getAsyn()])` instead of simpy `Product.getAsyn()`???

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, this is right. running ... normal output and after just runnning...running...running.... any output.

Comment: @bitifet because I need the response for the .then .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but it seems to me that you are misunderstanding promises.

Comment: Without Promise.all my code not working. What do you not understand?

Comment: Sorry. I'm writting from mobile app and sent the comment prematurely. Now to late to edit, so I paste the rest below: …If Product.getAsin is suitable for Promise.all, then (a) its returns a promise, so you can simply do `Product.getAsyn(…).then(…)` with the only difference that you will seceive the result as first parameter instead of an array with the result as its unique element. …or (b) it actually returns (synchronous) result in which case you perhaps were trying to promisify it. But the right (and clearer) way to do that is: `Promise.resolve(Product.getAsyn(…)).then(…)`

Comment: I found my problem ... In getAsin : I filter with a constant... With this updatedAt: { $lt: moment().subtract(1, 'minutes').toISOString() } it's ok. Otherwise I have to keep promise.all your solutions with a or b don't work : the promise stay in pending. It's not good ?

Comment: And only the last .catch is necessary ?

Comment: (a) and (b) weren't intended to be any kind of solution. Only hypothesis about Product.getAsync() behaviour. And, for sure, you can replace it by Promise.resolve() but then you should remove surrounding "[]" on its input parameter and on the arrow function passed to then() method one.

Even that arrow function is not a good idea: There is no need to use an arrow function there and, also, it makes code harder to read. Arrow function are designed for very specific use cases and *has sligtly different behaviour than normal functions* so using them for other cases is a bad idea. ;-)

Comment: About if only the last .catch is necessary it depends on how you chain promises. So true: Its the only necessary (and your code would become more readable and well structured) **if you do what I said before:** prepend `return` to `client.itemLookup(...)`. In fact, even its .then() could (and sould) be moved outside: `Promise.resolve(Product.getAsin()) .then(function (asin) { [...] return client.itemLookup({...}) }).then((results) => { [...] }).catch(function(err) { [...] });`